# Using database as cache. Rebuilding vs updating

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My question involves what the most efficient way to store an entire JSON document in a database table and refresh it periodically is.

Essentially, I'm calling the Google Analytics API once every 15 minutes via a cron job to pull out data about my site. I'm dumping this information into a sql table so that my front end application can search, sort and consume it. This JSON is paginated, such that only 5,000 rows come through at a time. I'll be storing as many as 100,000.

What I'm trying to do is optimize the way I rebuild the table. The most naive approach would be to truncate the table and insert every row from the JSON fresh. I have the feeling this is a bad approach, but maybe I'm underestimating sql.

I could also update each existing row and add new rows as necessary. However, I'm struggling with how I should delete old rows that might not be in the freshest JSON object.

Or perhaps I'm missing a more obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to this question is it depends on what works the best. As I am not familiar with the data I cant give you a straight forward answer but some guidelines.

Firstly 100 000 rows is nothing for a SQL server to handle. So truncating the table and inserting the values fresh might actually be workable, however if this data was to grow substantially this might not be a  solution that scales well. The main disadvantage to this approach is that for a period of time the table will be empty and this might be a problem for some users.

Summary of this approach:

1. Easy and quick to code and maintain.
2. Truncate will always be fast but insert will slow down as volumes increases.
3. Data will be offline during truncate and insert cycle.

Inserting and updating as we go along is known as Upserts/Merges. This approach will involve more work but the data will always be online. One of the difficulties you face is working with the JSON data and the SQL data(finding differences in the native JSON dataset compared to SQL table), this is going to be ineffective and cumbersome.

So I would create a staging table for the JSON. This table will be a exact copy of the final production table. I would then use LEFT and RIGHT JOINS to insert the new data and remove the deleted data. You could also create a hash for each row and compare these hashes to identify the rows that have changes and then update only were necessary. All these transformations can be handles in a simple SQL script. Yes you are underestimating SQL a bit...

Summary of this approach:

1. More complicated to code but not difficult to code simple joins and hash comparisons will do the trick.
2. Only insert new value, update changed values and delete old values. When scaling this solution it will eventually outperform the truncate, insert cycle.
3. Data remains online all the time.

If you need clarification around this please ask away.